# entityQuery vs. entityTypeManager

Tags: 8, entities, database

I have a custom content type `user_in_club` and I'd like to load a single specific node matching two field values. There are 2 ways (I know of) which can solve this:

```
$result = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
->condition('type', 'user_in_club')
->condition('field_user_id', $account->id())
->condition('field_club_id',$active_club)
->execute();
$nodes = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->loadMultiple($result);
```

OR

```
$nodes = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
->getStorage('node')
->loadByProperties(['type' => 'user_in_club', 'field_user_id' => $account->id(), 'field_club_id' => $active_club ]);
```

In my single example only one node id is returned, but in case I  have multiple node ids returned, is one method to be preferred over the other in terms of performance etc ? I currently don't see a big difference other than ETQ is better to create more complex queries.

Comment: loadByProperties uses = operator so if you need more advanced conditions, you have to use the query directly.

Comment: Thanks, yes that makes sense. I was just not sure if there is anything else that's different

Comment: With the lower level `entityQuery` you can also limit your result set via `$query->range(0, 100)` as an example. I don't believe you can do that with `loadByProperties` - correct me if I am wrong. So for smaller result sets `loadByProperties` might be more practical but as you suggest for more complex or performance-critical queries on large data-sets, `entityQuery` might be the way to go. Also you could call `entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->getQuery` which effectively does the same thing by exposing the more powerful query interface.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They're identical. loadByProperties() actually converts your conditions to an entity query internally.

I'd acually recommend to do an entity query yourself, directly. It's more readable and loadByProperties() might get deprecated in the future.

Comment: However, if I see Drupal.php file in core/lib directory, EntityQuery uses entity type manager which by itself uses getQuery, whereas loadByProperties uses getQuery, so I consider the other way round of deprecation as EntityTypeManger is used more than EntityQuery from inside.

Comment: For those writing OOP code, `entityQuery()` is deprecated in favor of `getQuery()`.  See: https://www.drupal.org/node/2849874

Comment: Note that loadByProperties does a loadMultiple and will load all the entities.